# Sum of 2 vectors

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, math

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3,2])
b = np.array([5,1])

x = a + b
plt.quiver(a,b,x)
plt.show()
print(x)
```

How to resolve this problem? I need to sum values of 2 vectors (first=[3,2] and second=[5,1]) and print this vectors on chart using matplotlib.

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect in the graph? Have you read the documentation of `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver`?

Comment: It looks like you just want to draw an [arrow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html)

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: Yes, i read docs about quivers but still not understand how it works

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import plt. Just add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` after `import numpy as np`
and don't forget to install matplotlib using `python -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Of course i added matplotlib later to try make chart, but i got line chart